# How to open & close a Window & UserControle in WPF MVVM Light?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, user-controls, mvvm-light

Lets say we have a mainWindow for the application and we want a second window or usercontrole (*whichever is best suited*) as a settings window. How would we open this window and close it with a mvvmLight approach?

This is currently the code i use for **opening** a new window(s).

```
var settingWindow = new SettingsViewWindow();
    settingWindow.Show();
```

This is currently the code i use for **closing** a window.

```
This.Close();
```

I don't know much about the userControle controle and when to use it. If you know  a youtube video or a site i could read about it it would be appritacted. Or just simply drop an explanation.

> Below is how i have structured the MenuItem Click Events. For the time beeing this is how i like to struckure my eventhandlers for buttons in general, and place them inside a descreptive regrion.
>   If i know how i would place this bottom part in a spolier. ;)

```
private void btnNav_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs
  {
    if(sender == btnNavSettings)
      {
          OpenSettingsWindow();
      }
      else if(sender == btnNavExitApp)
      {
          ShutDownApplication();
      }
   }

/// <summary>
/// Opens a settings window.
/// Only on settings window can be open at time.
/// </summary>
private void OpenSettingsWindow()
  {
    if(GlobalVariabels.GUI_Variabels.SettingsWindowIsOpen != true)
      {
         var settingWindow = new SettingsViewWindow();
         settingWindow.Show();
      }
  }

/// <summary>
/// Exit the application properly.
/// </summary>
private void ShutDownApplication()
  {
     Application.Current.Shutdown(0);
  }
```

Comment: What you are currenly doing violates a lot of MVVM principles. I'll add an explanatory answer when I get an access to a computer.

Answer (score 0):

You could for example pass a message between two Components, such as a view model and a view, using the `Messenger` class:

[MVVM Light WPF open new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781903/mvvm-light-wpf-open-new-window)
[How to open a new window using MVVM Light Toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386349/how-to-open-a-new-window-using-mvvm-light-toolkit)

Or you could create a dialog service that handles the opening of windows:

[Best Pratice to open a New Window in MVVM Light with Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198443/best-pratice-to-open-a-new-window-in-mvvm-light-with-parameters)

You then inject the view models with such a dialog service:

[Separate project for view models to "enforce" MVVM: How do I open dialogs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785499/separate-project-for-view-models-to-enforce-mvvm-how-do-i-open-dialogs/41790434#41790434)

There are plenty of links on the subject. Please refer to the ones I have supplied here and Google or Bing if you want more :)